# how to set position of <div> element based on another <div> element by CSS and BootStrap

Tags: css, bootstrapping

I develop bootstrap asp.net mvc. I have a  element that I want to place on right bottom of another  element.
I adjust it like this

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="vertical-align:middle; position:center;">
    <div class="row" style="vertical-align:middle; position:center;">
        @Html.DevExpress().ImageSlider(s =>
   {
       s.Name = "ImageSlider1";
       s.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
       s.Height = Unit.Pixel(400);

       s.SettingsImageArea.ImageSizeMode = ImageSizeMode.FillAndCrop;
       s.SettingsImageArea.NavigationButtonVisibility = ElementVisibilityMode.OnMouseOver;
       s.SettingsImageArea.EnableLoopNavigation = true;
       s.SettingsImageArea.AnimationType = AnimationType.Slide;
       s.SettingsImageArea.NavigationDirection = NavigationDirection.Vertical;
       s.SettingsNavigationBar.Position = NavigationBarPosition.Left;
       s.SettingsNavigationBar.PagingMode = NavigationBarPagingMode.Single;
       s.SettingsNavigationBar.Mode = NavigationBarMode.Thumbnails;



   }).BindToFolder("~/Content/Images/widescreen").GetHtml()


            <div id="countdown" style=" margin-top:62%; margin-right:3%;" >
                <div id='tiles'></div>
                <div class="labels">
                    <li>days</li>
                    <li>Hours</li>
                    <li>Min</li>
                    <li>Seconds</li>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

in CSS

```
    #countdown{
    width: 230px;
    height: 72px;
    position: relative-to first-sibling(.row); 
    bottom: 2px; 
    right: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222;
    background-color: transparent;
    /*background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7530a, #e6a815, #e6a815, #f7530a);*/ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, green,#fff, #fff, green);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 24px 0 2px 0;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

it OK like this picture. but i want this element fix to right bottom of that element even the windows size reduce or change

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Vrk.png)

Comment: My second <div> must be always be in the right bottom of first <div>. but when i change the browser size. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position an element so that it is always at the bottom right of it's container. You can use position relative on the container and position absolute on the child. This will position the child absolutely, relative to the container.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I remove style on second <div> and add your changes. but it doesnt work

Comment: when i use position: relative for parent, by changing windows size it will show scroll and it is not adaptive anymore

Answer (score 0):

use css like this

```
  .parent{
      position: relative;
    }
     .parent #countdown{
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       right: 0;   
     }
```

keep one thin in mind there no css property like **position: center;**.
remove margin-top and margin-right property from the #countdown div

Comment: what is the different when use add this code to site.css or bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: bootstrap.min.css is css library don't modify that instead of just put your new css in custom or site .css and override the bootstrap any class according to your taste i.e
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/your-custom.css">

Answer (score -1):

You can set the position parameters of a div like so:

```
<div class="myPageName" id="myElementID" style="position: relative; top: -20px; left: 10px; height: 100px; background-color: #212121" >
...
...
</div>
```